# Node.js iterate over Object key's keys

Tags: node.js, object

Ok so I know the title is a lil confusing (maybe a lot) so let me explain. In an Object variable like a mongoose schema there can be types as String, Number, Boolean, etc... But what if the type is a new Object? And what if that Object has another Object inside?

Let's say I got this schema in here:

```
user: {
    username: 'bob1',
    password: '1234',
    email: 'someone@example.com',
    profile: {
        name: {
            first: 'Bob',
            last: 'Marley'
        },
        gender: 'male',
        country: 'US'
    },
    userKeys: {
        username: { show: true },
        password: { show: false },
        email: { show: 'maybe' },
        profile: {
            name: {
                first: { show: true },
                last: { show: true }
            },
            gender: { show: false },
            country: { show: 'maybe' }
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to create a new temporary Object in my file based on that user's `userKeys` returning only the values from the schema that have the value `true` or `'maybe'` from the `userKeys` fields. How can I do that by iterating not only the keys from the basic structure but the keys inside the Object that is inside another Object? I have tried to do it with

```
Object.keys(user.userKeys).forEach((key) => {
    const cur = user[key];
    if (typeof cur === Object) {
        Object.keys(user.userKeys[key]).forEach((ok) => {
            console.log(ok, user.userKeys[ok].show);
            myObj.push(cur);
        });
    }
});
```

but it won't log anything that is a part of an Object (example: profile.name or profile.country).

I appreciate any tips.

Have a nice day

Comment: Recursion. See [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a simple function that takes an object and looks at each key to see if there is a `show: true` or maybe adding each one to an array. Then for each object you look at, you recursively pass that back into the function. This makes a very succinct solution:

```js
let object = {user: {username: 'bob1',password: '1234',email: 'someone@example.com',profile: {name: {first: 'Bob',last: 'Marley'},gender: 'male',country: 'US'},userKeys: {username: { show: true },password: { show: false },email: { show: 'maybe' },profile: {name: {first: { show: true },last: { show: true }},gender: { show: false },country: { show: 'maybe' }}}}}

function getTrueKeys(obj, res = []) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k => {
        if (obj[k].show && (obj[k].show === true || obj[k].show === 'maybe')) res.push(k)
        if (typeof obj[k] === 'object') getTrueKeys(obj[k], res)
    })
    return res
}

console.log(getTrueKeys(object.user.userKeys))
```